# TeXworks 'search and find' window

Tags: texworks

When I used the included TeXworks in texlive 2014, then whenever I did a search (Ctrl+F in Windows) for a character string in my `.tex` file, then the top section of my window would display all the hits for said string. With TeXworks in texlive 2015, this no longer happens. Now whenever I do a search, it just takes me straight to the next instance of that string. I can't find any setting that will allow me to change this behavior and let me see that top window again. Does anyone know?

Comment: When you hit `CTL-F` to "find", one of the boxes to check is "Find all occurances".  When this is checked, the box will appear with all matched cases.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Oh boy, indeed! You want to provide an answer, or is this so silly that I should just delete my question?

Comment: Your call.  I will be happy to convert comment to an answer, unless you prefer to delete.  I seem to recall a similar confusion once upon a time.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Well if you've seen/experienced the same confusion, too, then I'll keep the question, and you can add the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When one invokes the Find function (with `CTL-F`) in TeXworks, a window pops up

[image]

One of the boxes that can be checked is `Find all occurrences`.  If that box is not checked, the search will just take you to the next occurrence in the file.  If that box is checked, it will bring up the window that displays all hits for the entered string.

Given the number of settings in that window, it is easy to "glaze over" and miss the particular one to which I draw attention.

The setting is "persistent", by which I mean that once you check or uncheck the box, all your future searches retain that setting, until you change it again.

My guess, in the OP's case is that the default (installation) setting for the search mode was **NOT** to find all occurrences, so the OP merely need to check that box the next time find is invoked, and should be good to go.